# Why can't non-superuser see data in stl_load_errors in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

The [Amazon Redshift documentation for stl_load_errors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) states that "This table is visible to all users." However, I get different results when querying as a superuser (936 rows) vs a non-superuser (0 rows). Why does the query run as the non-superuser return 0 rows?

Here are the queries I ran.

Superuser:

```
$ psql -U masteruser -h XX.XX.XX.XX -p 5439 bi -w -c "select count(*) from stl_load_errors"
 count 
-------
   936
(1 row)
```

Non-superuser:

```
$ psql -U emonsen -h XX.XX.XX.XX -p 5439 bi -w -c "select count(*) from stl_load_errors"
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

Furthermore I can use [HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE.html) to show that Redshift thinks "emonsen" has the correct privileges on stl_load_errors:

```
$ psql -U masteruser -h XX.XX.XX.XX -p 5439 bi -w -c "select has_table_privilege('emonsen', 'stl_load_errors', 'select')"
 has_table_privilege 
---------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 6):

the solution here is to be granted with the ***SYSLOG ACCESS*** permissions. Here is the documentation: [AWS - Visibility of Data in System Tables and Views](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_visibility-of-data.html)

Answer (score 6):

Any user can see all the stl_load_errors results of other users by granting access to syslog as shown below here.

alter user username SYSLOG ACCESS { UNRESTRICTED }

Comment: This solution worked for me. The GRANT solution did not.

Answer (score 1):

You are right! This table is visible to all users, but the catch here is Masteruser can see all the load errors across all users.
Whereas other users can see their own error logs only. In your case 'emonsen' can see his own error logs only, as in load error generated by 'emonsen'. Nothing wrong with privileges

Comment: Is there any way to allow "emonsen" to see load errors across all users?

Comment: Unfortunately no! only masteruser has that privilege.